# Wifi keeps disconnecting (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, broadcom, disconnect

I have a dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 machine. I can connect to Wifi fine on Windows, but when using Ubuntu it disconnects every 10-20 minutes or so. When this happens, I can always get it working again with:

```
sudo rmmod wl
sudo modprobe wl
```

I've tried suggestions from similar posts (e.g., disabling IPv6, setting `REGDOMAIN=GB` in `/etc/default/crda` and installing `linux-firmware`), but nothing has worked so far. I'd be very grateful if anybody could help.

Output from `lspci -nn -d 14e4:`

```
21:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
```

Output from `journalctl"` around time of disconnect:

```
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3 (SSID='Careline Wireless' freq=5240 MHz)
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 geoclue[1644]: Failed to query location: Error resolving “location.services.mozilla.com”: Temporary failure in name resolution
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745551.4197] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Associated with 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3 completed [id=0 id_str=]
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: bgscan simple: Failed to enable signal strength monitoring
Oct 15 08:05:51 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745551.4878] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Oct 15 08:05:52 jack-MS-7C02 code.desktop[4422]: [main 2020-10-15T07:05:52.330Z] update#setState idle
Oct 15 08:06:23 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 18:e8:29:67:f8:9d (SSID='Careline Wireless' freq=2437 MHz)
Oct 15 08:06:23 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745583.1708] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: completed -> associating
Oct 15 08:06:23 jack-MS-7C02 kernel: ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : 
Oct 15 08:06:23 jack-MS-7C02 kernel: Wrong Mac address, mac = 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3   profile =18:e8:29:67:f8:9d
Oct 15 08:06:23 jack-MS-7C02 kernel: ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : 
Oct 15 08:06:23 jack-MS-7C02 kernel: Wrong Mac address, mac = 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3   profile =18:e8:29:67:f8:9d
Oct 15 08:06:27 jack-MS-7C02 kernel: ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : 
Oct 15 08:06:27 jack-MS-7C02 kernel: Wrong Mac address, mac = 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3   profile =18:e8:29:67:f8:9d
Oct 15 08:06:27 jack-MS-7C02 kernel: ERROR @wl_cfg80211_get_station : 
Oct 15 08:06:27 jack-MS-7C02 kernel: Wrong Mac address, mac = 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3   profile =18:e8:29:67:f8:9d
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Authentication with 18:e8:29:67:f8:9d timed out.
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=18:e8:29:67:f8:9d reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: nl80211: Was expecting local disconnect but got another disconnect event first
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <warn>  [1602745593.1701] sup-iface[0x55c1d41a8910,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745593.1709] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=USER type=COUNTRY alpha2=GB
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Oct 15 08:06:33 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Failed to initiate AP scan
Oct 15 08:06:34 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Oct 15 08:06:34 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Failed to initiate AP scan
Oct 15 08:06:34 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 18:e8:29:67:fb:e3 (SSID='Careline Wireless' freq=2412 MHz)
Oct 15 08:06:34 jack-MS-7C02 geoclue[1644]: Failed to query location: Error resolving “location.services.mozilla.com”: Temporary failure in name resolution
Oct 15 08:06:34 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745594.7696] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> associating
Oct 15 08:06:44 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Authentication with 18:e8:29:67:fb:e3 timed out.
Oct 15 08:06:44 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=18:e8:29:67:fb:e3 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Oct 15 08:06:44 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <warn>  [1602745604.7632] sup-iface[0x55c1d41a8910,wlo1]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct 15 08:06:44 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745604.7685] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Oct 15 08:06:44 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745604.8882] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 15 08:06:46 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 18:e8:29:68:fb:e3 (SSID='Careline Wireless' freq=5240 MHz)
Oct 15 08:06:46 jack-MS-7C02 geoclue[1644]: Failed to query location: Error resolving “location.services.mozilla.com”: Temporary failure in name resolution
Oct 15 08:06:46 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745606.5059] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Oct 15 08:06:46 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=18:e8:29:68:fb:e3 status_code=16
Oct 15 08:06:46 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745606.5717] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Oct 15 08:06:46 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745606.6720] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 15 08:06:48 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 18:e8:29:67:f8:78 (SSID='Careline Wireless' freq=2412 MHz)
Oct 15 08:06:48 jack-MS-7C02 geoclue[1644]: Failed to query location: Error resolving “location.services.mozilla.com”: Temporary failure in name resolution
Oct 15 08:06:48 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745608.3074] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Oct 15 08:06:48 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=18:e8:29:68:fb:e3 status_code=16
Oct 15 08:06:48 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745608.3555] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Oct 15 08:06:49 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745609.3571] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 15 08:06:50 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 18:e8:29:68:f8:9d (SSID='Careline Wireless' freq=5180 MHz)
Oct 15 08:06:50 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745610.9553] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Oct 15 08:06:51 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=18:e8:29:68:fb:e3 status_code=16
Oct 15 08:06:51 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Careline Wireless" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Oct 15 08:06:51 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745611.0197] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Oct 15 08:06:56 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745616.0236] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Oct 15 08:06:57 jack-MS-7C02 geoclue[1644]: Failed to query location: Error resolving “location.services.mozilla.com”: Temporary failure in name resolution
Oct 15 08:06:59 jack-MS-7C02 systemd[1830]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Oct 15 08:06:59 jack-MS-7C02 dbus-daemon[950]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.bluez' unit='dbus-org.bluez.service' requested by ':1.123' (uid=1000 pid=5315 comm="/opt/google/chrome/chrome " label="unconfined")
Oct 15 08:06:59 jack-MS-7C02 systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Oct 15 08:06:59 jack-MS-7C02 gnome-keyring-daemon[1858]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/Default_5fkeyring/1, but it's already registered
Oct 15 08:06:59 jack-MS-7C02 gnome-keyring-daemon[1858]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/Default_5fkeyring/1, but it's already registered
Oct 15 08:07:00 jack-MS-7C02 gnome-shell[5323]: Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Oct 15 08:07:00 jack-MS-7C02 gnome-shell[5323]: [5355:5355:1015/080700.530435:ERROR:shared_image_manager.cc(214)] SharedImageManager::ProduceSkia: Trying to Produce a Skia representation from a non-existent mailbox.
Oct 15 08:07:01 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="Careline Wireless"
Oct 15 08:07:01 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: Trying to associate with 18:e8:29:67:f8:78 (SSID='Careline Wireless' freq=2412 MHz)
Oct 15 08:07:01 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745621.6160] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> associating
Oct 15 08:07:01 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT bssid=18:e8:29:68:fb:e3 status_code=16
Oct 15 08:07:01 jack-MS-7C02 wpa_supplicant[981]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="Careline Wireless" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Oct 15 08:07:01 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745621.6758] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Oct 15 08:07:03 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <warn>  [1602745623.8441] device (wlo1): link timed out.
Oct 15 08:07:03 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <info>  [1602745623.8443] device (wlo1): state change: activated -> failed (reason 'supplicant-timeout', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Oct 15 08:07:03 jack-MS-7C02 gnome-shell[2059]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Oct 15 08:07:03 jack-MS-7C02 NetworkManager[952]: <warn>  [1602745623.8468] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'Careline Wireless'
Oct 15 08:07:03 jack-MS-7C02 gnome-shell[1595]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following post today. Can you try to change your SSID name to all lower cases and see if that fix the issue? I'm not sure what the problem is, but it might worth a try.

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=249140

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem started after i set MAc address to random on garuda linux this mess up the wifi on both garuda and windows dual boot, i tried every post i found,nothing worked
a clean install of ubuntu fix did not fix it, niether setting mac address back to default fixed the problem.
i ended up deleting both windows and garuda, i only left untouch the home partition

```
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off
cd /etc/pm/
sudo -H gedit wifi_pwr_off
```

this will open a blank file, copy this to blank file:

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iwconfig wlp2s0 power off
```

save the file and close

```
sudo chmod u+x wifi_pwr_off
```

done